# Adding C++11 object to list when dynamically allocated?

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose I have a class X:

```
struct X
{
   ...
};
```

And I have a global vector V:

```
vector<X*> V;
```

I want to add a new instance of X to V if and only if it is dynamically allocated (as a complete most derived object, not a subobject):

```
int main()
{
    X x; // not added to V
    new X; // added to V

    struct D : X {};
    new D; // not added to V
}
```

Is there some way to do this?  Perhaps by overloading/overriding `operator new` somehow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Building on [aschepler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/459640/aschepler)'s approach, but now using a virtual base class to redirect `D`'s constructor calls (to not add an instance to the vector).

Main idea is to do a two-step registration: first, register any call to `operator new` (whether it's for `X` or a derived class) to an `unordered_set` (`X::dyn_alloc_set`). Then, when constructing `X`, selecting based upon the most-derived type, add `this` to `V` if it has been dynamically allocated **and** if it's not a derived class.

The constructor of a virtual base class has to be called from the most-derived type, therefore you can use it to differentiate between `D` and `X` during construction.

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

struct X;
std::vector<X*> V;

struct virt_base_class
{
    friend struct X;
private:
    virt_base_class(X* p);  // this can only and will only be called by X
public:
    virt_base_class()  // this will be called by any class derived from X
    {}
};

struct X
    : protected virtual virt_base_class
{
private:
    friend class virt_base_class;
    static std::unordered_set<X*> dyn_alloc_set;
    static bool dynamically_allocated(X* p)
    {
        return dyn_alloc_set.count(p) > 0;
    }    

public:
    X()
        : virt_base_class(this)
    {}

    static void* operator new(std::size_t size) {
        void* p = ::operator new(size);
        if (size == sizeof(X))
            dyn_alloc_set.insert( static_cast<X*>(p) );
        return p;
    }
    static void operator delete(void* p, std::size_t size) {
        if (size == sizeof(X))
        {
            dyn_alloc_set.erase( static_cast<X*>(p) );
            V.erase( std::remove(V.begin(), V.end(), static_cast<X*>(p)),
                     V.end() );
        }
        ::operator delete(p);
    }
};


virt_base_class::virt_base_class(X* p)
{
    if( X::dynamically_allocated(p) )
        V.push_back(p);
}

struct D : X
{};  // D::D will implicitly call virt_base_class::virt_base_class()


std::unordered_set<X*> X::dyn_alloc_set;


int main()
{
    X x;
    X* p = new X;
    D d;
    D* pd = new D;

    std::cout << V.size();
}
```

---

Update: using `thread_local` storage to avoid the `unordered_set`:

```
struct X
    : protected virtual virt_base_class
{
private:
    friend class virt_base_class;
    static thread_local X* last_dyn_allocated;
    static bool dynamically_allocated(X* p)
    {
        return p == last_dyn_allocated;
    }

public:
    X()
        : virt_base_class(this)
    {}

    static void* operator new(std::size_t size) {
        void* p = ::operator new(size);
        if (size == sizeof(X))
        {
            last_dyn_allocated = static_cast<X*>(p);
        }
        return p;
    }
    static void operator delete(void* p, std::size_t size) {
        if (size == sizeof(X))
        {
            X* pp = static_cast<X*>(p);
            if(last_dyn_allocated == pp)
                last_dyn_allocated = nullptr;

            V.erase( std::remove(V.begin(), V.end(), pp),
                     V.end() );
        }
        ::operator delete(p);
    }
};

thread_local X* last_dyn_allocated = nullptr;
```

Comment: `typeid` won't return a derived class ID during a constructor, just like virtual functions will not call the derived versions. 12.7/5.

Comment: Yes, I suspect `typeid(this)` inside a base class constructor is potentially UB.

Comment: It's well-defined.  Inside a constructor or destructor of `X`, even if called indirectly, `typeid(*this) == typeid(X)`.

Comment: Removed the dependency on `typeid`, replaced by virtual base class.

Comment: +1 Wow, finally a use-case for virtual base classes and their weird construction rules, amazing!

Answer (score 8):

```
struct X {
public:
    static void* operator new(std::size_t size) {
        void* p = ::operator new(size);
        if (size == sizeof(X))
            V.push_back(static_cast<X*>(p));
    }
    static void operator delete(void* p, std::size_t size) {
        if (size == sizeof(X))
            V.erase(std::remove(V.begin(), V.end(), p), V.end());
        ::operator delete(p, size);
    }
};
```

Note that there will be times when elements of `V` point at memory that is not yet or no longer actually an `X`.  It's possible for users to get around these functions, but they'd have to be trying.

If you have another class that inherits `X` but has the same size (so no other subobjects except maybe "empty" base classes), like `struct Y : public X {};`, the code above will think `new Y` is allocating an `X`.  If this is an issue, you'd need to also add `operator new` and `operator void` to every such class `Y`.  I don't think there's a more general solution.

Comment: Does a subclass necessarily have a larger size?

Comment: No, they could be the same size.

Comment: If X were polymorphic, perhaps there is a way to dynamically determine if its most derived class is X at some point after recording the pointer.  I'm not sure but I think inside `X::X` is too early to be able to do this.

Comment: @user1131467: But `new` is invoked *before* the constructor, so if it's too early inside `X::X`, it's too early even inside `new`

Comment: @AndyProwl: I didn't disagree.

Comment: @user1131467: I guess overloading new in the subclasses so that it does *not* add the pointer to the vector is out of the question, right?

Comment: @AndyProwl: Sure, it is a solution - just a bit of ugly code duplication for every subclass.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approximation to what you want is to force the use of a factory for dynamically allocated objects:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

class X {
  static std::vector<X*> dynamic_xs;

  static void* operator new(std::size_t size) {
    return ::operator new(size);
  }

public:
  ~X() {
    auto end = std::end(dynamic_xs);
    auto pos = std::find(std::begin(dynamic_xs), end, this);
    if (pos != end) {
      if (pos != --end) {
        std::iter_swap(pos, end - 1);
      }
      dynamic_xs.pop_back();
    }
  }

  template <typename... Args>
  friend X* make_x(Args&&... args) {
    X* p = new X(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    dynamic_xs.push_back(p);
    return p;
  }
};

std::vector<X*> X::dynamic_xs;
```

Clients can instantiate stack-allocated `X`, but dynamic allocation will cause an access error since `operator new` is `private`.